# Can yield from a context manager (or similar) multiple times after exception?

Tags: python, yield, contextmanager

I'd like to report multiple errors while processing a list:
For example:

```
with MultipleExceptions.testItems(items) as value:
   ... process value
   if value==3: raise Exception("3 err")
   if value==5: raise Exception("5 err")
```

should possibly collect and report an exception for *each* value of items that raises an exception in the block (not just the first).

The naive implementation:

```
class MultipleExceptions(Exception)
   @staticmethod
   @contextmanager
   def testAllItems(items):
       errs = []
       for i, value in enumerate(items):
          try:
             yield value
          except Exception e:
             errs.append(i,e,value)

       if errs: ... compose and raise mega exception message
```

... fails because context managers can only yield once. Its not obvious why this has to be true. Is there a way to yield multiple times?

As a generator:

```
for value in MultipleExceptions.testAllItems(items):
   ... process value
   if value==3: raise Exception("3 err")
   if value==5: raise Exception("5 err")
```

```
class MultipleExceptions(Exception)
   @staticmethod
   def testAllItems(items):
       errs = []
       for i, value in enumerate(items):
          try:
             yield value
          except Exception e:
             errs.append(i,e,value)

       if errs: ... compose and raise mega exception message
```

... fails because the exception is never caught within testAllItems.

Clearly I could wrap my block into a function and provide that to a utility (without yield):

```
def f(value):
   ... process value
   if value==3: raise Exception("3 err")
   if value==5: raise Exception("5 err")

MultipleExceptions.testItems(items, f)
```

... but yielding to a block with a generator or context manager seems so much cleaner and requires less work form the caller. Is possible to get to treat a block more like a function to run many times?

Answer (score 4):

> ... fails because context managers can only yield once. Its not obvious why this has to be true. Is there a way to yield multiple times?

No, because context managers *don't yield*.

Context managers are a way to perform setup and teardown around a block of code. Their `__enter__` method gets called when the `with` block is entered, and their `__exit__` method gets called when the `with` block ends. `__exit__` can suppress exceptions, but aside from that, that's the entirety of their functionality. Neither `yield` nor any sort of implicit loop is involved.

`@contextlib.contextmanager` is merely a tool for creating context managers. It creates a context manager whose `__enter__` runs the generator until it yields, and whose `__exit__` resumes the generator *once*, and expects the generator to end after that. This is occasionally a convenient way to express setup and teardown code, but it cannot change how the context manager protocol actually works.

Comment: Sure. I explained that context managers don't solve this in the question.
But that's only because the context manager expects just a single result.
But it doesn't seem like that need to be a constraint of yields, and context blocks generally - its just how @contextlib.contextmanager did things, right?

Comment: @user48956: I get the feeling you're thinking of `yield` like it's Ruby. Python `yield` works totally different from Ruby `yield`. Neither context managers nor anything built on top of `yield` will get you what you want.

Comment: (I don't think even Ruby `yield` would be enough, anyway - you'd also need a way to resume from exceptions, which has historically turned out to be way too problematic to be a worthwhile feature for a language.)

Comment: @user2357112 I'm curious what you find problematic about continuable errors. As I allude to in my answer, Common Lisp did this decades ago to great success. And much more recently, Raku elected to support the same. Which parts of this feature do you dislike?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: The place where the exception occurred is usually "too deep" to be an appropriate place to resume, plus you often end up with bugs from resuming at points that weren't designed to be resumed from.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no way to *resume* from a `raise` statement in Python. Once you unwind the call stack to a particular point, you can't go back. Some languages do allow jumping back to the erroneous stack frame, such as [Raku's `resume`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/resume) or [Common Lisp's `continue`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/r_contin.htm), but this feature is not available in Python.

Generally, what we tend to do in Python is accumulate a list of errors and throw them all at once. It's not pretty or automatic like your proposed context manager, but it works.

```
errors_list = []
if value == 3:
    errors_list.append(Exception("3 err"))
if value == 5:
    errors_list.append(Exception("5 err"))

# At the end ...
if errors_list:
    raise MyCustomError(errors_list)
```

In fact, Python 3.11 and newer come with [*exception groups*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/) that do just this. You still have to accumulate the errors yourself, but then the `ExceptionGroup` provides a nice `except*` syntax for handling different error types.

```
errors_list = []
if value == 3:
    errors_list.append(Exception("3 err"))
if value == 5:
    errors_list.append(Exception("5 err"))

# At the end ...
if errors_list:
    raise ExceptionGroup("Message summarizing the exceptions", errors_list)
```

Then, to handle them,

```
try:
    call_possibly_failing_function()
except* SomeExceptionType as e:
    # Handle all the SomeExceptionType's in the group ...
except* SomeOtherExceptionType as e:
    # Handle all the SomeOtherExceptionType's in the group ...
except* Exception as e:
    # Handle all uncaught exceptions ...
```

Note that, in these `except*` blocks (as opposed to ordinary `except` blocks), the variable `e` is of type `ExceptionGroup`. You can iterate over the exceptions *in* that group with

```
for exc in e.exceptions:
    ...
```

Comment: Re: "no way to resume from a raise statement in Python." That seems a problem with context manager and generators, not exception handlers generally. If context manager's block where instead a function to be called with a list element parameter, clearly, this would be trivial.

Comment: Even if a context manager took a function, raising an exception in the context manager block would unwind the stack. The fundamental limitation here is that, once you unwind the stack to find an exception handler, you can't "un-unwind" it and go back. If Python kept the original call stack live during exception handling like Raku does, then you could, but it doesn't.